# Getting a console application to allow input multiple times

Tags: c#, console-application

I made a console application that calculates the number of days since a user-specified date. But after the original calculation, if another date is typed in, the application closes.

Is there a way I can get my application to not close if the user wants to continue using it?

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the date you wish to specify: (DD/MM/YYYY)");
        string userInput;
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        DateTime calc = DateTime.Parse(userInput);
        TimeSpan days = DateTime.Now.Subtract(calc);
        Console.WriteLine(days.TotalDays);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Please post the code that you are using so that we can best tell you how to modify it and explain where you are going wrong.

Comment: Apologies, code is now there!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement a while loop:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the date you wish to specify: (DD/MM/YYYY)");
string userInput;
userInput = Console.ReadLine();
while (userInput != "0")
{
    DateTime calc = DateTime.Parse(userInput);
    TimeSpan days = DateTime.Now.Subtract(calc);
    Console.WriteLine(days.TotalDays);
    Console.WriteLine("Add another date");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Pressing 0 and enter will exit.

Answer (score 3):

Put your code into a loop and let the user have a way to quit the application.

For example

```
Console.WriteLine("Press q to quit");

bool quitFlag = false;
while (!quitFlag )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the date you wish to specify: (DD/MM/YYYY)");
    string userInput;
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if (userInput == "q")
    {
        quitFlag = true;
    }
    else
    {
        DateTime calc = DateTime.Parse(userInput);
        TimeSpan days = DateTime.Now.Subtract(calc);
        Console.WriteLine(days.TotalDays);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This will allow the user to quit the application by entering "q".