# Count Vowel and Consonant C#

Tags: c#

**Question**

Take input of 1 character from user. It can be the vowel or consonant.
After the user gives input so it will ask do you want to input the character again for Yes press Y and for No press N.

When the user says No, you have to show how much vowel and how much consonant use has input.

Please do this question using For loop. I think array must be use. I did this code it counting vowel and consonant and spacing. But I cant take the input multiple times.

My code doesnn't run multiple times. I can only write sentence or a character in a line so it will only count that. But I want to ask the user to enter a character again.

I want my code to run multiple times so the user can give input multiple times as I explain my question.

```
    using System;
public class vowelConsonant
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int vowels = 0;
        int consonant = 0;
        int space = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a Sentence or a Character");
        string v = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

        for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
            {
                if (v[i] == 'a' || v[i] == 'e' || v[i] == 'i' || v[i] == 'o' || v[i] == 'u')
                {
                    vowels++;
                }

                else if (char.IsWhiteSpace(v[i]))

                {
                    space++;
                }

                else
                {
                    consonant++;
                }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Your total number of vowels is: {0}", vowels);
        Console.WriteLine("Your total number of constant is: {0}", consonant);
        Console.WriteLine("Your total number of space is: {0}", space);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

Thanks
```

Comment: there is no question there.  does it work? whats doesnt it do?

Comment: `But I cant take the input multiple times.` You need to use a loop for that. This is a very basic question. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118495/getting-a-console-application-to-allow-input-multiple-times can help you.

Comment: What if you enter numbers? Or special characters (e.g. `"#"`).

Answer (score 0):

Just put an infinite loop around the whole thing.

```
using System;
public class vowelConsonant
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Infinite loop.
        while (true)
        {
            int vowels = 0;
            int consonant = 0;
            int space = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a Sentence or a Character");
            string v = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
            {
                if (v[i] == 'a' || v[i] == 'e' || v[i] == 'i' || v[i] == 'o' || v[i] == 'u')
                {
                    vowels++;
                }

                else if (char.IsWhiteSpace(v[i]))

                {
                    space++;
                }

                else
                {
                    consonant++;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Your total number of vowels is: {0}", vowels);
            Console.WriteLine("Your total number of constant is: {0}", consonant);
            Console.WriteLine("Your total number of space is: {0}", space);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This application to count vowels and consonants letters in a sentence.
This is another solution with less line of codes with understanding idea of using loop and nested loop with char arrays.

[Application interface with controls names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPSJs.gif)

```
namespace Program8_4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // declare the counter variables in field
        int iNumberOfVowels = 0;
        int iNumberOfConsonants = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // call the methods in this event
            GetVowels(txtStringInput.Text);
            GetConsonants(txtStringInput.Text);
            // show the result in a label
            lblOutput.Text = "The number of vowels : " + iNumberOfVowels.ToString() + Environment.NewLine+
                "The number of consonants : " + iNumberOfConsonants.ToString();
            // assign zero the counters to not add the previous number to new number, and start counting from zero again
            iNumberOfVowels = 0;
            iNumberOfConsonants = 0;
        }

        private int GetConsonants(string strFindConsonants)
        {
            // Declare char array to contain consonants letters
            char[] chrConsonants = { 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'X',
                'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'x' };

            // loop to get each letter from sentence
            foreach (char Consonants in strFindConsonants)
            {
                // another nested loop to compare each letter with all letters contains in chrConsonants array
                for (int index = 0; index < chrConsonants.Length; index++)
                {
                    // compare each letter with each element in charConsonants array
                    if (Consonants == chrConsonants[index])
                    {
                        // If it is true add one to the counter iNumberOfConsonants
                        iNumberOfConsonants++;
                    }
                }
            }
            // return the value of iNumberOfConsonants
            return iNumberOfConsonants;
        }

        private int GetVowels(string strFindVowels)
        {
            // Declare char array to contain vowels letters
            char[] chrVowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O','U' };

            // loop to get each letter from sentence
            foreach (char Vowels in strFindVowels)
            {
                // another nested loop to compare each letter with all letters contains in chrVowels array
                for (int index = 0; index < chrVowels.Length; index++)
                {
                    // compare each letter with each element in chrVowels array
                    if (Vowels == chrVowels[index])
                    {
                        // If it is true add one to the counter iNumberOfVowels
                        iNumberOfVowels = iNumberOfVowels+1;
                    }
                }
            }
            // return the value of iNumberOfVowels
            return iNumberOfVowels;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can simply find the required vowels and consonant counts using **Regex.Matches()** function.

> Below is the working code snippet:

```
 public static void Main()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Enter a Sentence or a Character");
       string input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

       string vowels = @"[aeiouAEIOU]+"; //regular expression to match vowels
       string consonants = @"[^aeiouAEIOU]+"; //regular expression to match consonants
       string space = @"[\S]+";
       int vowLength = new Regex(vowels).Matches(input).Count;
       int conLength = new Regex(consonants).Matches(input).Count;;
       int spLength = new Regex(space).Matches(input).Count;;

       Console.WriteLine("Your total number of vowels is: {0}", vowLength);
       Console.WriteLine("Your total number of constant is: {0}", conLength);
       Console.WriteLine("Your total number of space is: {0}", spLength);
   }
```